# How to remove broken images coming via api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api

I am writing a project in which I receive data from the server about different films, but in one of the genres a huge number of pictures are broken and it does not come out beautifully.

**An example to understand what it looks like:**
[image]

I need to remove broken pictures from the film's row. **I tried to fix it using the error handler - onError:**

```js
 const [showImage, setShowImage] = React.useState(true);

  const hideImg = (e: any) => {
    setShowImage(false);
  };
  
      <div>
        {showImage ? (
          <img
            src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${item?.backdrop_path}`}
            alt={item?.title}
            onError={hideImg}
          />
        ) : null}
      </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

As a result, broken images still take up space and this is not what I need...
**Result:**
[image]

**I get data from the server like this:**

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    try {
      axios.get(fetchURL).then((res) => {
        setMovies(res.data.results);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error>", e);
    }
  }, [fetchURL]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe it's possible to catch broken images in a try/catch block and remove them? I will be grateful for the answer

Comment: Sounds like its the `<div>` that takes up space. Your CSS does this.

Comment: The absence of the div does not solve the problem...